# How to restore encrypted files after reinstalling Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, encryption

So I had some encrypted files using the Windows file encryption on NTFS disk and I reinstalled windows xp. After that I logically couldn't access the encrypted files because of the encryption. 
Is there a way how to recover those files so I could access them? Reading Google most people say I'm booned, but I hope that I'm not and there is a chance to get all those files back..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have backed up your key ( `.PFX` file which contains your `.CER` file) then you simply need to import it and log off, then back on and your files should be accessible.

If you never backed up your key, I am guessing it is brute force time, but I wouldn't know where to begin to advise you here.

Comment: This is also assuming you aren't part of a domain that assigned a EFS Restore account and cert..

Comment: I just know the SID I had on that windows user. Does it help somehow? Maybe I can replace the current sid with the sid I had on the old windows user?

Comment: And no I don't have any backups for certificates - because I didn't know about this problem before. :(

Comment: @Richards sorry, nope, I don't think this SID has any relationship with the encryption certificate.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, they point of encryption is to prevent access in such a case. The only possible way is if you had restore a certificate set up or if you want to attempt to crack the encryption.

Comment: Check my comment on Wil's answer. Maybe the sid can help somehow?